# Discord.js specific channel

Tags: discord.js, channel

I have such a problem that I want to send a message via the bot only to a given channel. How can I do this?

```
Client.channels.cache.get(id).send(text)
```

This don't work

Comment: Which version of Discord JS are you using? You can check that in `package.json`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors/warnings? Please show as much code as possible and explain in detail what went unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like so with discord.js v12:

```
let channel  = client.guilds.cache.get('ID_of_the_guild_in_which_the_channel_is_in').channels.cache.get('channel_ID');
if(channel) channel.send('your message');
```